# The Functional FizzBuzz Kata

Tags: beginner, f#, fizzbuzz

I run a coding dojo at work. For one session I'm to showing that you can use a kata to get into a new language.

I'm using the FizzBuzz Kata to to show F# (and JavaScript) because it is short.  The problem is I am very new to F# and find myself devolving to objects instead of being functional.

Thus, I would like to see better ways of doing this (using nunit):

```
namespace FizzBuzzFSharp
    open NUnit.Framework

    module FizzBuzzer = 
        let FizzBuzz number = 
            match number with 
            | i when i % 3 = 0 && i % 5 = 0 -> "FizzBuzz"
            | i when i % 5 = 0 -> "Buzz"
            | i when i % 3 = 0 -> "Fizz"
            | _ -> number.ToString()


        [<Test>]
        [<TestCase(1, "1")>]
        [<TestCase(2, "2")>]
        [<TestCase(3, "Fizz")>]        
        [<TestCase(4, "4")>]
        [<TestCase(5, "Buzz")>]
        [<TestCase(6, "Fizz")>]
        [<TestCase(7, "7")>]
        [<TestCase(8, "8")>]
        [<TestCase(9, "Fizz")>]
        [<TestCase(10, "Buzz")>]
        [<TestCase(11, "11")>]
        [<TestCase(12, "Fizz")>]
        [<TestCase(13, "13")>]        
        [<TestCase(14, "14")>]
        [<TestCase(15, "FizzBuzz")>]        
        [<TestCase(30, "FizzBuzz")>]
        let WhenNumber_ThenResult(number, expected) = 
            Assert.AreEqual(expected, FizzBuzz(number));
```

Comment: Sister question: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/64869/the-scripted-fizzbuzz-kata

Comment: Here's how I did it: http://blog.ploeh.dk/2012/07/20/FizzBuzzkatainFstage1

Comment: @MarkSeemann I know, your blog was my starting point of reference.  As I was not sure how to get [<Theory>] and [<InlineData>] to work, I dropped back to Nunit and Test / TestCase. (once I got the unit testing I did build it up test first, but as you can see from the outcome the details of your solution stuck in my fingers - down to the names and solution pattern)

Comment: Are you interested primarily in better ways to write the tests or more idiomatic ways to implement the function itself?

Comment: @mattnewport on the rare occasions that I venture into the F# world I find myself leaning on an OO crutch. I quite like the tests, so I'm looking for nice ways to write the F# function. (do you not like the test?)

Comment: I don't think there's anything wrong with the tests, I just didn't see any obvious 'leaning on an OO crutch' in your fizzbuzz function - your implementation seems fine to me. The typical thing you see programmers new to F# do is use an `if .. then` rather than pattern matching in this sort of situation when pattern matching is more idiomatic but you haven't done that. That said, I posted a slight variant below which I think is a bit more 'functional'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your implementation is fine. I might write it like this, because I find it more idiomatic in F# to avoid guards (`when` clauses) in pattern matching where a guard free implementation is equally concise.

```
let fizzbuzz x = 
    match (x % 5, x % 3) with
    | (0, 0) -> "FizzBuzz"
    | (0, _) -> "Buzz"
    | (_, 0) -> "Fizz"
    | _ -> string x

[1..100] |> List.map fizzbuzz |> List.iter (printfn "%s")
```

There are ways you can make this more elaborate / extensible but while that can be an interesting exercise I don't think they're really an improvement over a simple straightforward implementation like this.